# Access an array like a stack using top_of_stack(n).value

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

TOS means top of stack. Example of the expected usage,

```
 read: var xx = tos(3).value;
write: tos(4).value = 12345678;
```

Given an array

```
var mystack = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55];  // 55 is tos(0), 22 is tos(3)
```

Reading `mystack` is easy, `tos(0).value` returns 55, `tos(1).value` returns 44, following
function does well,

```
function tos(n){
    arguments.callee.value = mystack[mystack.length - 1 - n];
    return arguments.callee;
}
```

But I want to write data to `mystack` by

```
tos(2).value = 3333;  // How to make tos() work this way?
```

`mystack` should become `[11, 22, 3333, 44, 55];` How to re-write `tos()` for this?

Why ask the question?

Microsoft office Excel automation allows objExcel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(1,1).value to be at either side of = , for example,
objExcel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(1,1).value = 11223344;
WScript.echo(objExcel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(1,1).value); // prints 11223344

I try to access an array that way but found it difficult to me.

The expected function tos() is an Encapsulation that avoid from exposing mystack itself.

Comment: that's weird code, seriously

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, and frankly I don't see the point, then you can do:

```
function tos (n) {
    var i = mystack.length - n - 1;
    return Object.defineProperty ({}, "value", {
       get : function() { return mystack[i]; },
       set : function(v) { mystack[i] = v; }
    });
}
```

Of course you'll need ECMAScript 5. There is no other way to achieve the semantics you want of `tos(2).value=999` setting an array element, since in JS, the `.value` syntax requires the object on the left be an object, and an array element in of of itself is not an object with a value that can be set. So the above essentially constructs an object and defines a getter and setter on it.

To make this independent of `mystack`, do the obvious:

```
function as_stack (array) {
    return {
        tos : function (n) {
            var i = array.length - n - 1;
            return Object.defineProperty ({}, "value", {
                get : function() { return array[i]; },
                set : function(v) { array[i] = v; }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Now you can do

```
as_stack (array).tos (2).value=999;
```

or

```
var tos = as_stack (array).tos; 
tos (2).value = 999;
```

if that floats your boat.

Depending on your religious persuasions about such things, you could also add this to `Array.prototype`:

```
Array.prototype.tos = function (n) {
    var i = this.length - n - 1, array = this;
    return Object.defineProperty ({}, "value", {
        get : function() { return array[i]; },
        set : function(v) { array[i] = v; }
    };
};
```

Now you can do

```
array.tos (2).value=999;
```

**Another approach**

If you're fixated on using the `.value` syntax for getting and setting values, without using `Object.defineProperty`, then the only other alternative I can think of is to use the DOM as a proxy for an array. We will store the array as a list of text nodes in a document fragment. However, you will have to use `nodeValue`, not `value`.

First, create a DOM-based array from a real array:

```
function dom_array (array) {
    this.frag = document.createDocumentFragment ();
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        this.frag.appendChild (document.createTextNode (array[i]);
    }
}
```

Now, you can do

```
my_dom_array = new dom_array ([1,2,3]);
```

Next, we will add a method to return a specific element:

```
dom_array.prototype.tos = function (n) {
    return this.frag.childNodes.item (this.frag.childNodes.length - n -1 );
}.
```

This function actually returns a DOM text node, which you can now use to do things like:

```
my_dom_array.tos (2).nodeValue = "bar";
alert (my_dom_array.tos (2).nodeValue);
```

You'll probably want to add a member function to get back a real array:

```
dom_array.prototype.to_array = function () {
    var array=[];
    for (var i=0; i<this.frag.childNodes.length; i++) {
        array.push (this.frag.childNodes[i].nodeValue);
    }
    return array;
};
```

Now you'd probably also want to implement all the other array methods like `push` or `pop` or whatever on this quasi-array.

There you have it--a `tos` function which allows you to get and set values in an array, albeit using `nodeValue` instead of `value`. However, it strains the imagination as to why you would want to do this instead of just saying `array[2]=999;` like every other JS programmer in the world.

Note that this would not work in a non-DOM environment, such as node.js.

Comment: I upvoted because you mentioned getters and setters, but your code still needs some tweaking

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a good way. Microsoft office Excel automation allows objExcel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(1,1).value to be at either side of = , I found that I don't know how to do that.

Comment: tos() returns an object is enlightening. But the tos(n).value appears at left of = should be a feference. Why Excel can do that?

Comment: Excel is Excel, and JavaScript is JavaScript. Language designers can do anything they want.

Comment: Thank you very much. JScript on Windows 8 does not support Object.defineProperty I need to work out an alternative way. Thanks again.

Comment: I think you're confused. JavaScript does not depend on the OS, it depends on the browser. And any browser running on Windows 8 will support this. Perhaps you are referring to IE8. However, there is no way to implement the syntax you want without Object.defineProperty getters and setters. And why did you want to do this again? It's JS, when in Rome, just do `array[2]=y;`, or `array[arrya.length-2]=y;` if you're so sure that arrays should be indexed from the top. Better yet, why not just go write your app in Excel which implements the syntax of which you are so enamored?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you control `mystack` variable, just build it differently, and life will get much easier.

Take advantage of JavaScript.Array's `shift` and `unshift` operators.  Start with your stack empty:
    mystack = [];

When you add to it, simply shift the value:

```
mystack.shift(11);
mystack.shift(22);
mystack.shift(33);
mystack.shift(44);
mystack.shift(55);
```

Then it will be a 0-indexed stack, and `mystack[2]` will give you 33, and you can simply do `mystack[2] = 3333` to set your value.

To "pop" the stack, use `unshift`.  It will remove the 0 element.

Comment: The tos() is about encapsulation. I don't want to be tied on the name 'mystack'. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous commenter pointed out, your code above was quite weird. To make your code look better, if `mystack` is really used as `Stack` in the sense of the `Stack` data type, use the following:

```
mystack.push(11);
mystack.push(22);
mystack.push(33);
mystack.push(44);
mystack.push(55);
```

Certainly then you are going to have `[11, 22, 33, 44, 55]` in the stack. To peek at the stack top, you may want a function like this:

```
function peek(stack) {
  return stack[stack.length - 1];
}
```

Or you can define it in `Array.prototype` as:

```
Array.prototype.peek = function () {
  return this[this.length - 1];
};
```

Then you can access your stack top with `mystack.peek()`. Now you have the proper semantics of a `stack`. While you shouldn't really access elements inside a stack directly, you will still have the option to modify them with `mystack[2] = 2222` if really necessary.

Comment: The tos() is about encapsulation. I don't want to be tied on the name 'mystack'. Thank you anyway.